# Error During creating new project in vs 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]

It is happening for any kind of project.
Can any body have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve it by modifying the vs.

First uninstall win 10 sdk and emulator from system and then install it again.

Problem will be resolved.